# Yii language sourceLanguage and translations

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to translate a app in many languages, using `Yii MVC`;

In `main.php` i have set `language => en_us`;

When I try using `Yii::t('file','key')` i get the `key` as is was written, not the translated text.

Comment: Have you created the relevant files in /protected/messages?

Comment: so, i messed up; but my way is the way i need the app to work;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this might happen because your source and current languages are equals and they set to "en". As example. If you want to translate from english to russian you must set current language as "ru" and source language must be "en". Here details http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n.